# Como hago para mostrar un resultado comparando entre un rango ruby

Tags: array, ruby

```rb
def scan_addicts2(array)
  results=[]
  números = array.count
  números.time do |i|
    if array[i] < 90
      results.push 'bien'
    elsif array [i]

    else array[i] >= 180
      results.push 'mal'

...
```

Lo único que me falta es donde va el elsif colocar que si hay un número entre 90 y 180 "puedes mejorar"

Pero no logro saber como

Comment: Bienvenido al sitio, es importante realizar preguntas en el sitio en base a el documento [ask], te sugerimos editar tu pregunta y agregar lo que has tratado o investigado, **agrega el código como texto por favor** ya que puede no ser visible para algunos usuarios. No olvides realizar el [tour] del sitio para conocer su funcionamiento básico, saludos.

Comment: Si copias/pegas tu código es mucho más fácil de ejecutarlo en nuestros propios equipos y ver cuál es el problema. Saludos

Answer (score -1):

Me parece que lo que quieres hacer se logra con:

```
elsif array[i] > 90 && array[i] < 180
```

Comment: hola gracias, ya lo coloque 

 def scan_addicts2(array)
  results=[]
  numeros = array.count
  numeros.time do|i|
    if array[i] < 90
      results.push 'bien'
    elsif array [i]> 90 && array[i] < 180
      results.push 'mejorable'
    else array[i] >= 180
      results.push'mal'
end
end
end

scan_addicts2(array)

PERO NOSE COMO LLAMARLO PARA QUE ME FUNCIONE EN LA TERMINAL